# How to draw a thick line using a rectangle?

Tags: c++, opengl

Hello I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

My current code for achieving this in OpenGL is the following:

```cpp
void draw_thick_line(vec2 start, vec2 end, GLfloat thickness) {
    GLfloat slope_angle = atanf((end.y-start.y)/(end.x-start.x));
    GLfloat b = (M_PI/2) - slope_angle;
    GLfloat y_shift = thickness*sinf(b)/2.0f;
    GLfloat x_shift = thickness*cosf(b)/2.0f;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(start.x - x_shift, start.y - y_shift);
    glVertex2f(start.x + x_shift, start.y + y_shift);
    glVertex2f(end.x + x_shift, end.y + y_shift);
    glVertex2f(end.x - x_shift, end.y - y_shift);
    glEnd();
}
```

But the following does not achieve what I want consistently. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? My guess is something about `x_shift` and `y_shift`.
[image]

Also if this is the wrong place to post this please do inform me, and I will change it.

Comment: Your title says something about a quadrilateral, but the drawing that you have labeled "I'm trying to achieve the following" has a simple rectangle. Are you saying your code isn't drawing the rectangle properly? You said, *...does not achieve what I want consistently*. Are you saying it works sometimes? Or what do you mean by *consistently*? As an aside, you can achieve your calculations with ratios and simple algebra. You don't need to use trigonometry.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: @lurker Yes I meant rectangle, and by inconsistency I mean that the width of the line is not always the desired width, for the second image, all of them are meant to have the same width, but they don't.

Comment: Okay - use `atan2`, not `atan`. `atan` can't distinguish between quadrants 1 and 3, or 2 and 4. `atan2` takes two arguments and will preserve the sign required for a correct angle.

Comment: @3Dave Oh yeah I did forget about that, but for some reason, it still doesn't work...

Comment: I suggest making a really thick line, by itself, and rotating it slowly through a full circle. See if you can get a better idea of under which circumstances its the width is changing. Nothing obvious is jumping out at me at the moment.

Comment: You might try flipping the signs on ` glVertex2f(end.x + x_shift, end.y + y_shift);` and similar lines. I'd expect this to be more like `glVertex2F(end.x+x_shift, end.y - y_shift)`. But, again, without a runnable version, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @3Dave As you mentioned flipping around some signs fixed this issue, but I accepted lurkers answer since his was faster. Instead of (+, +) and (-, -), I needed to do (+, -) and (-, +)

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it fixed. :) In the future, I'd recommend just using a scale & rotation matrix on a rectangle instead. BUT, since you have something that works, go with it!

Comment: Not promoting my own site, but here's an explanation of rotation matrices I put together for a class I taught a few years ago: http://davidlively.com/programming/graphics/opengl-matrices/rotation-matrix/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your angle calculation is not quite correct:

```
GLfloat b = (M_PI/2) - slope_angle;
```

This gives you the complement of `slope_angle` *within the same quandrant* but is not the correct angle relative to the coordinate system and doesn't transform you to the line segment you need.

I think the correct angle calculation would be:

```
GLfloat b = (M_PI/2) + slope_angle;
```

Your "width" line segment is at an angle of PI/2 degrees *more* than the angle of the original line segment.

You could also achieve this by swapping the sign of the `x_shift` as was noted in the comments since you have:

```
sin(pi/2 + b) = sin(pi/2 - b)
cos(pi/2 + b) = -cos(pi/2 - b)
```

You could also avoid the trig functions using similar triangles, something like:

```
void draw_thick_line(vec2 start, vec2 end, GLfloat thickness) {
    GLfloat d = sqrt((end.x - start.x)*(end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y)*(end.y - start.y));
    GLfloat y_shift = thickness*(end.x - start.x)/(d * 2.0f);
    GLfloat x_shift = -thickness*(end.y - start.y)/(d * 2.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(start.x - x_shift, start.y - y_shift);
    glVertex2f(start.x + x_shift, start.y + y_shift);
    glVertex2f(end.x + x_shift, end.y + y_shift);
    glVertex2f(end.x - x_shift, end.y - y_shift);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Also as @3Dave mentioned if you did use '-' instead of '+', you could use (-x_shift, +y_shift) / (+x_shift, -y_shift), instead of (+x_shift , +y_shift) / (-x_shift, -y_shift)

Comment: Nice explanation. +1

Comment: @ChrisGeorge yes, that works, as indicated by the trig identities I cited in my answer. The sign of the `x` shift flips.